# libgdx tiled map get player position in whole map to make a minimap

Tags: libgdx, tiled

Actually I draw a part of my tiled map using camera zoom (with `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer` on my main camera). Camera is centered on player position (who is always at center of the screen) in a box2d world.

```
// Set camera postion center on player (box2d body) on every update
camera.position.set(player.getBody().getWorldCenter(), 0);
```

I would like to create a minimap with a second camera. A simple filled rectangle with a point who represent player position on map.
So I created a new camera :

```
minimapCamera = new OrthographicCamera(1280, 720); // as my main camera
minimapCamera.zoom = 6; // larger zoom
minimapCamera.position.set(-1280 * 2, 720 * 3, 0); // align bottom right corner
```

And I try to draw shapes :

```
ShapeRenderer sr = new ShapeRenderer();
sr.setAutoShapeType(true);
sr.setProjectionMatrix(minimapCamera.combined);
sr.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
sr.setColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.3f);
// minimap rectangle background
sr.rect(0, 0, minimapCamera.viewportWidth, minimapCamera.viewportHeight);
sr.setColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 0.4f);
// player circle point
sr.circle(playerPos.x, playerPos.y, 20);
sr.end();
```

But how can I calculate the player position `playerPos` in the whole tiled map ? And how to draw only a part of zoomed map ? (I don't want to draw all map but a more larger section than my main camera).

EDIT :
If I want to reuse my tiled map in my minimap, how can I draw only player visible section in the minimap (at the moment, all the map is rendered even if I specify a small camera size) ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your tile map makes use of rows and columns and each cell has a set width and height, you can get the player's position in the tile map array like this (hope you don't mind JavaScript):

```
var player={x:200,y:200};/* Or whatever position. */
var tile_width=tile_height=32;/* Or whatever dimension you're using. */

player.tile_x=Math.floor(player.x/tile_width);
player.tile_y=Math.floor(player.y/tile_height);
```

This gives you the exact x and y tile the player occupies in the world.

Comment: I think you have to adjust the math to consider the current viewport, as he might not be drawing/seeing the entire map at once?